# javascript moment the mouse is held down

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

How do I get the coordinates from my mouse with JavaScript? How can I hold only the coordinates of the moment the mouse is held down?

Comment: Post the code like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please provide some code that you have tried.

Comment: There is a mousedown event, listen for that and the relevant values from the event object dispatched when it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mousedown` event is your friend. Just click and hold on the gray area:

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#x')
var y = document.querySelector('#y')

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  x.innerText = e.clientX
  y.innerText = e.clientY
}, false)
```

```css
#target {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
X: <span id="x"></span><br>
Y: <span id="y"></span>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a canvas on where the user can click on and catch the mouseDown event and you can get the current mouse position by following this example and snippet
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp

```
var x = event.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
var y = event.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate
var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
```